# Does opening an iphone app via URL still call applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: iphone, initialization

If you open up an iphone app from a custom url scheme, does the `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method still get called?

In my app I create a `UITabBarController` with 4 `UIViewControllers` in my `applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. If my app is closed and I open it from the custom url, do I also need to create the `UITabBarViewController` and `UIViewControllers` in the `openURL:sourceApplication:annotation` method?

Answer (score 3):

The discussion in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) for

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```

states that

> If an application is launched as a result of another application
>   requesting it to open a URL resource, UIApplication first sends the
>   application a application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: message and
>   then it invokes this method. This method supplies the delegate of the
>   handling application with the bundle ID of the source application as
>   well as any annotation information from that application. If an
>   application is already running when it receives a request to open a
>   URL, this method is called but
>   application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: isn’t.